# How do I reset: sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, sonoma, pmset

I was messing around with [`pmset`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) and I added this setting: `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1` in my terminal. I have got [Amphetamine](https://iffy.freshdesk.com/support/home) for my Mac, so I want to take off this `pmset` setting. How could I?

Answer (score 2):

Why not document all your settings and then reset the SMC to see what the defaults are across the board?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102605

You can then change only the ones you need should you have others you tweaked over time.

Comment: Thank you! I did a SMC reset and then inputted sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0 . Since 0=false, I fixed it.